# Add new cell in tableView from textfield

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I created a table and a text field. I want the table to create a new cell every time the user writes something in the text box.I have a code like this. I created an array for names and try to fill cells with it, but so far there is no result.

```
var playerName = [String]()
    @IBAction func addPlayerNameTextFieldAction(_ sender:UITextField)
    {

        let name = addplayerTextFiedOutlet.text!
        playerName.append(name)

        addplayerTextFiedOutlet.resignFirstResponder()
        playerListTableView.reloadData()
    }




func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = playerListTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: idCell, for:indexPath) as! PlayerListTableViewCell
            cell.playerNameLabel.text =  playerName[indexPath.row]

        return cell
}
```

Comment: What does *no result* mean?

Comment: I enter the words in the text field, press return and no action. Even the keyboard does not disappear.

Comment: Is the action called at all? Please use the debugger.

Comment: after clicking on the text field, a keyboard appears, I can enter text but nothing happens next. I tried to output the array to a string and it didn’t output anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to perform your action when press return key on the keyboard you should implement the UITextfieldDelegate method and set keyboard delegate to your controller and do stuff in this method

in your viewDidLoad method :

```swift
textfield.delegate = self
```

then impelement delegation method:

```swift
extension YourviewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {   //delegate method
   let name = addplayerTextFiedOutlet.text!
        playerName.append(name)
        addplayerTextFiedOutlet.resignFirstResponder()
        playerListTableView.reloadData()
        return true
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately this did not work for me. It still doesn’t respond to Return

Comment: did you set your textfield delegation ?  first you should conform your viewController to UITextfieldDelegate and then set your textfield delegation to viewcontroller and then this method should work

Comment: At first I added a delegate, but it did not work, then I did it through the extension and everything is fine. Thanks You so mutch!